# How to solve complex triple integrals involving square roots

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I came a cross this problem while doing calc homework:

> Use a triple integral to find the volume of the solid bounded below by the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and bounded above by the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 722$. ([Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjI0v.png))

I can figure out what the triple integral is supposed to be:

$$
\int_{-\sqrt{361}}^{\sqrt{361}}
\int_{-\sqrt{361 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{361-x^2}}
\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{722-x^2-y^2}}
dz~dy~dx
$$
Because $z$ is bounded by the cone on the lower side and the sphere on the higher side so these can be plugged in directly, then $y$ is bounded by the the chord of the circle where the cone and the sphere intersect orthogonal to the $xz$ plane at a given $x$ value, and $x$ is bounded by the max radius of this sphere.

Slightly simplified:
$$
\int_{-\sqrt{361}}^{\sqrt{361}}
\int_{-\sqrt{361 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{361-x^2}}
\left(
\sqrt{722-x^2-y^2} - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\right)
~dy~dx
$$

I also figure that this inner integral can be probably be solved using trigonometric substitution, but that would yield some nasty inverse trig functions.

Which brings me to my question which is:

Is there a more elegant solution to this integral besides trig substitution?

Or is there a simpler (or more correct) integral that can be used to solve this problem?

---

*For what its worth I plugged the inner integral into wolfram and got:*

$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(y \left(\sqrt{-x^2 - y^2 + 722} - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right) + x^2 \left(-\log \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + y\right)\right) - \left(x^2 - 722\right) \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{-x^2 - y^2 + 722}}\right)\right) + C
$$
*Which looks a bit much but maybe wolfram just didn't simplify it well*

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Both of the surfaces bounding the region are level surfaces of one the standard spherical coordinates, $\rho, \theta, \phi$.

> **Additional hint.** For example, the sphere can be written as $\{\rho = \rho_0\}$, where $\rho_0$ is the radius $\sqrt{722} = 19\sqrt{2}$ of the sphere.

After you determine the equations of the two surfaces in spherical coordinates, can you write the triple integral that represents (in terms of the spherical coordinates) the volume of the region they bound?